# How to plot a function and data at the same time?

Tags: plotting

I know that ListLinePlot allow to plot data, but I would like to compare my data with some analytic function in the same plot. Is it possible to listlineplot data and plot a function at the same time?

Comment: Try using  `Show`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Show[]` to combine plots.  E.g. `Show[plot1, plot2]`.

Answer (score 3):

A trivial way (many ways to do this...)

```
data = Range@100;
myF[x_] := x^1/2 + Sin[x];
ListLinePlot[{data, myF /@ data}]
```

[image]